# Removing a particular color/background in C# PictureBox

Tags: c#, forms, background, picturebox, transparent

I am attempting to remove a white background from my pictureboxes in my C# Form as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYcM6.jpg).

I have already tried to use `BackColor = Color.Transparent;` , however, this did not work.

Is there another way to go about this? Perhaps a function which would allow me to remove the white color?

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: for confirmation purpose , this is a WinForms application or WPF ?

Comment: @AnuViswan yes WinForms application

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a .png image that's support transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your background in the picture is transparent
Then add this code:

`this.*picturebox1.Parent = this.Form1**; 
 this.*picturebox1.BackColor = Color.transparent;`

Note:
* = whatever name that your named your picture box

** = any structure can be, e.g = panel, picture box etc